# How to get user specific data from firebase in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firstly I've reviewed Firebase documentation, they only have two separate explanations on login user and CRUD operations but not really how both they can be connected with security rules. Despite that I've worked on it here is the security rules. In iOS code I fetch the list and also add the item with user id

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /contacts/{creatorsID} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == creatorsID;
    }
  }
}
```

```
ERROR: Write at contacts/wv6fMMhBpw3ROEOyUMBe failed: Missing or insufficient permissions
```

```
{ creatorsID: "", name: "" }
```

```
func fetchData() {

    db.collection("contacts").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
        }

        self.contacts = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Contact in
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let userID = data["creatorsID"] as? String ?? ""
            return Contact(name: name)
        }
    }
}
```

```
func addData(name: String) {
    do {
        _ = try db.collection("contacts").addDocument(data: ["name": name, "creatorsID": Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid])
    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I still receive all the items from all users instead of specific user's list(FYI, CreatorsId is as same as UID). I can't figure out if the issue is in rules or in iOS code.

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: there is no error neither in code nor in firebase @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Still, please replace all screenshots with the code, rules error message as text.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting all users because you read the data with:

```
db.collection("contacts").addSnapshotListener...
```

So this gives you all documents from the `contacts` collection. If you want to only read a single document, you'll have to identify that document either by its ID or by [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

---

Since you use `addDocument` to add the document, Firestore generates a unique ID for you. That means that with your current data structure, the way to get the user document is by querying on the `createdID` field:

```
db.collection("contacts")
  .whereField("createdID", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
  .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
    ...
```

---

A more idiomatic way to store user profile documents is to use the UID of each user as the ID of the document too. That both guarantees that each user can only have one document (as document IDs are by definition unique within a collection), and it means you can look up the profile document for a user without a query:

```
db.collection("contacts")
  .document(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
  .addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
    ....
```

Doing this will also solve your security errors, as this code matches exactly with what you're checking here:

```
match /contacts/{createdID} {
  if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == createdID
```

In your current approach the value of `createdID` is the random ID that Firestore generates when you call `addDocument`, and not the user's UID.

Comment: I have added this restriction. Thank you it worked charm.
Do you have any suggestion on security rule how to restrict it. Currently it's failing with the rule that I have added.(Refer above, I've added the rule and error, it is clearly failing the second boolean of if condition)

Comment: I upvoted :) actually if you see my addData method,  I am explicitly setting userid in created id and cross checked in the database it is user id in that property. Unfortunately that rule doesn't allow me to add it:(

Comment: Setting a `createdID` field inside a document is not the same as setting the document ID, and your security rules are checking the document ID - and not for a field in the data. Did you try the code with `.document(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)` from my answer yet?

Comment: that's interesting documentId comparison by firebase "request.auth.uid == creatorsID".


.document(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)

- this method doesn't work for me because it returns only one document whereas my DB has several documents.